# Prime Number Counter (Sieve of Eratosthenes) Using MPI, Too Slow

Tags: performance, mpi, overhead, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The following code counts up all of the prime numbers until 50,000,000 and works 100% correctly. The problem is that it takes way too long. With 32 processors, I got about 42 seconds. A peer of mine got 16 seconds and I just can't seem to find where my code is lagging. Please leave any suggestions :)

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

const int n=50000000;   //number until which primes are counted (inclusive)

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long local_count=0, global_count=0,     //variables used to keep count of the primes
    start, finish,      //highest and lowest possible primes for this processor 
    i;  

    int rank,           //processor id 
    p,          //number of processes
    size, proc0_size;   //amount of numbers to check on any processor and proc 0
double runtime;         //variable used to keep track of total elapsed time

    //initialize the MPI execution environment
    MPI_Init (NULL, NULL);

    //determine the rank of the calling processor in the communicator
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        //determine the size of communicator
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    //Ensures that every processor enters code at around the same time
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //Start the timer
    runtime = -MPI_Wtime();

    //compute the range and size to be used for this processor
    start = 2 + rank*(n-1)/p;
    finish = 1 + (rank+1)*(n-1)/p;
    size = finish - start + 1;

    //determine the size of processor 0
    proc0_size = (n-1)/p;

    //in the case where there are too many processors for the amount of numbers
    //to check...   
    if ((2 + proc0_size) < (long) sqrt((double) n)) {
        if (rank == 0)
            printf ("Too many processors to calculate the number of primes up to %d\n", n);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    int j;
    //check every number in the range of this processor
    for (j=start; j<=finish; j++){
     //if the number is not composite, ie prime, increment the local counter
     if (isComposite(j)==0){
        local_count++;
     }
     }

     //MPI_Reduce used to combine all local counts
         MPI_Reduce (&local_count, &global_count, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

     //adjust the total elapsed runtime
     runtime += MPI_Wtime();
     printf("Process %d finished\n", rank); 

     // print the results from process ranked root
     if (rank == 0) {
            printf ("There are %ld primes less than or equal to %d\n", global_count, n);
        printf ("Total elapsed time:  %f seconds\n", runtime);
     }

     //terminate the execution environment
     MPI_Finalize ();
     return 0;
   }

//function to check if a number is composite
//returns 0 if it is not composite (prime) and returns a 1 if it is composite

int isComposite (int num){

int retval=0;

if(num==1)
        retval = 1;

   else if(num%2 == 0 && num!=2)
        retval = 1;

    if(retval != 1) {
    int j;
    for(j=3; j<num; j+=2) {
                if(num%j == 0 ){
                        retval = 1;
                        break;
                }
                if(j*j>num) break;
            }
    }

if(retval == 0)
    return 0;
else 
    return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your test and run it on local machine.

I got

```
 3001134 primes less than or equal to 50000000
```

with `Total elapsed time:` around 35-37 seconds. My PC has 4 cores of Q6600 at 2.4 GHz, 64bit ubuntu. Test compiled as `mpicc t.c -o t -lm -O3`.

With only two cores - time is 66 seconds.

What I noted: the processes with higher rank got more work to do, and they ends their computation later than processes with lower ranks. So, when you are using lot processes, the total execution time is defined by the last process with highest rank.

Try to redistribute work (give less segment for processes with higher ranks) and optimize your `isComposite` function. As I see in result of profiling with `perf record`, the `num%j == 0` line takes a lot time (around 80%).

It can be better to prepare list of small primes and sieve with them as first step, switching later to more expensive sieving.

Also sieving means not iterating `j` over start..finish and testing each `j`, but creating of array from start..finish, then iterating with `i` - every number less `sqrt(finish)`, and marking `array[2*i]`, `array[3*i]`, `array[4*i]`, `array[5*i]` etc as composite (you can use addition instead of multiplication). Then you will count non-marked elements from array to get prime numbers from the interval. (Do check the animations from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Your code is the slowest possible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Comment: After implementing simples sieve, my program can find all primes up to 500000000 (ten times than in your original case) in 21 seconds on 2 or on 4 CPUs. Original size - 2.2 - 2.6 seconds. PS: verification tables are here: http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml